# Fread unusual line ending causing error

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am attempting to download a large database of NYC taxi data, publicly available at the [NYC TLC website](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml).

```
library(data.table)
feb14 <- fread('https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2014-02.csv', header = T)
```

Executing the above code successfully downloads the data (which takes a few minutes), but then fails to parse due to an internal error.  I have tried removing `header = T` as well.

Is there a workaround in order to deal with the "unusual line endings" in `fread` ?

```
Error in fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2014-02.csv",  : 
  Internal error. No eol2 immediately before line 3 after sep detection.
In addition: Warning message:
In fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2014-02.csv",  :
  Detected eol as \n\r, a highly unusual line ending. According to Wikipedia the Acorn BBC used this. If it is intended that the first column on the next row is a character column where the first character of the field value is \r (why?) then the first column should start with a quote (i.e. 'protected'). Proceeding with attempt to read the file.
```

Comment: I wish I knew that the few minutes would be 20 and the file size is >2 gigs :). Anyways, I will look at it as soon as the file is read.

Comment: Btw, a [mcve] is preferred here. In this case, minimal might mean making an example that isn't 2 GB; and reproducible would mean not using a link that's liable to break at some point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes other options like read.csv/read.table *can* behave differently... so you can always try that. (Maybe the source code tells why, havent looked into that).

Another option is to use readLines() to read in such a file. As far as I know, no parsing/formatting is done here. So this is, as far as I know, the most basic way to read a file

At last, a quick fix: use the option 'skip = ...' in fread, or control the end by saying 'nrows = ...'.

Comment: What does `...` do and what should be skipped ?

Comment: The dots mean a value that you can enter on your own :)

Comment: I understand so that means I should skip until line 3?

Comment: As an example... you can try


your_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyctlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2014-02.csv'
feb14 <- fread(your_url,skip = 10,nrows = 20, header = T)



Or if you want to try readLines..

feb14 <- readLines(your_url,n = 20)

Comment: You can indeed try to skip the first couple of lines to see if that works. I am behind a proxy now, so it is a bit difficult for me to read from this url.
Let me know if the code suggestions helped

Comment: Fyi, backticks can be used to delineate code in comments or answers (e.g. to not create an invalid link as in your earlier comment).

Comment: `skip = 10` produces the same error just `No eol2 immediately before line 11`.   If we use `readLines()` how would one then parse that single column into a regular dataframe?

Comment: My way to deal with this is to use something like str_split or the like... However, I tried to reuse your code.. and found out that the file is quite large. For testing these kind of things, please use a subset of such a large set to identify the problems. 
Hence, download the set itself, then subset it by looking at the first few lines using some command line options.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issues might be caused due the presence of a blank line between the header and data in the original .csv file. Deleting the line from the .csv using notepad++ seemed to fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is something fishy with `fread`. `data.table` is the faster, more performance oriented for reading large files, however in this case the behavior is not optimal. You may want to raise this issue on [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues)

I am able to reproduce the issue on downloaded file even with `nrows = 5` or even with `nrows = 1` but only if stick to the original file. If I copy paste the first few rows and then try, the issue is gone. The issue also goes away if I read directly from the web with small `nrows`. This is not even an `encoding` issue, hence my recommendation to raise an issue.

I tried reading the file using `read.csv` and `100,000` rows without an issue and under 6 seconds.

```
feb14_2 <- read.csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2014-02.csv", header = T, nrows = 100000)
```

`header = T` is a redundant argument so would not make a difference for `fread` but is needed for `read.csv`.